# Is it possible to drop_last in reverse with PyTorch's DataLoader?

Tags: pytorch, dataloader

I'm currently trying to make a custom PyTorch DataLoader.

I'm aware that setting `drop_last=True` when first declaring the DataLoader object tells the object to drop the last incomplete batch if the size is not appropriate. However, I was wondering if that could be done in reverse, where the DataLoader computes the number of batches and counts from the back.

The reason I'm asking this is because the data that I'm currently using is time series data, and I want to use the most recent sample and therefore it would be ideal if the "leftover" samples were dropped from the oldest portion of the data.

I've thought of ways like reversing the data to start with, then creating the DataLoader object and reversing it back to the way it was, or to first reverse the data and create the object and then feed in the `idx`'s in reverse order when running `__getitem__`, but this seems troublesome and prone to making errors so I was wondering if PyTorch offers this behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Computing the number of samples which will be removed is relatively straightforward. Once you have that number then you could use [`torch.utils.data.Subset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.Subset) to truncate your data from the start. For example

```
batch_size = ... # your batch size
dataset = ... # your dataset

# compute number of samples to remove
dropped_samples = len(dataset) - batch_size * int(len(dataset) // batch_size)

subset_dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, range(dropped_samples, len(dataset)))
loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(subset_dataset, ...
```

In this case setting `drop_last=True` would have no effect since `len(subset_dataset)` is divisible by `batch_size`.